# Regex expression to match " delineated string

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I'm trying to use regex to do a syntax highlight to match strings. The problem that I'm having is that in programming editors, strings still get highlighted when there is no closing double quotes.

The way I'm going about doing the actual syntax highlighting is with an event on TextChange, removing all highlights on the visible text, and rehighlighting.

So essentially, I would want to match the following:

- "adfads"
- ""
- "asdfadf  (ending at the end of the line would be fine)
- Not match // "", but I could probably end up doing that somewhere else.

etc.

What I've tried:

- \"[^\"]*\" - Worked, but will only highlight when you close the "s
- \".*?\"?? - only matches the "s because it matches the first match, which would just be the first ".
- \".*\" - Same problem as the first but less specific of a search.

Like I said, I have a fairly simple way of doing the highlights -

```
private void CodeEditor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CodeEditor.VisibleRange.ClearStyle(StringsStyle);
    CodeEditor.VisibleRange.SetStyle(StringsStyle, "<HERE IS MY REGEX>");
}

private void CodeEditor_VisibleRangeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CodeEditor_TextChanged(null, null);
}
```

I am beginning to think, that unless I can get the regex to only match the last match, it cant be done this way. Though maybe something to do with using either the " or the end of the line?

Comment: The '$' dollar sign character matches the end of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, if `\"[^\"]*\"` *mostly* works for you, try `\"[^\"]*(\"|$)`. This in theory should match something with quotes on either end, *or* something started by a quote and ended by the end of the line.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know you could do something like this or this. As it happens, because of how this textbox works apparently, the $ applies to the end of the string, not the line and works as multiline string highlighting aswell. Is there any way to make this work for backslashed strings? or rather strings with backslashed "'s

Comment: You can use `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\"` to only match an unescaped quote. So I guess your overall expression would be something like `\".*?($|(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\")` - note how I've switched from "not a quote" ('[^\"]') to "anything, but don't be greedy" ('.*?') in the middle. (I can't try this right now, but give it a try.)

Comment: It's telling me not enough )'s (when it displays the error, it does so without the escaped backslashes as: ".*?($|?<!\)(?:\\*"). EDIT: and upon adding another \\ to the first one in the first group, it ceases erroring, but didn't solve the problem

Comment: For your "without escaped" bit it looks like you're missing a few things... without escaping it should be `".*?($|(?<!\)(?:\\)*")`.

Comment: I probably copied it wrong, because the error now shows the same as your last comment, but it still errors telling me that I don't have enough )'s (despite it having two closing and 2 opening!) I've gone back to using your original \".*?($|(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\"), but it errors unless I change it to this: \".*?($|(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\)*\"), which no longer works between lines, and doesnt fix the backslashes

Comment: OK... I've tried the following in plain C# and it seems to work: (spacing spacing spacing spacing spacing) `"\".*?(?:$|(?:(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\"))"` Note how (a) the slashes are QUADRUPLED, because you need two slashes in a C# string literal to become one slash in the actual string, and two slashes in the actual string to become one slash in the regex (double escaping ftw!), and (b) the right-hand side of the pipe is now a group, because I forgot to do that. Give that a shot...

Comment: Your original solution worked multiline, though this one doesnt. But this one now correctly works with escaped double quotes, which is much more important to me. Thanks a lot!